# What is the best way to count the number of entries across 3 dataframes that aren't shared?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have three dataframes that are summaries of various statistics about countries.  I've created a join of the three dataframes on the 'Country Name' column.  But I want to know how many entries exist in the three original dataframes that were excluded from the join. Whats the best way code wise to count this?

Comment: Please provide some [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Though I feel like you should just do an outer join and check columns that are all null

Comment: Without example data, you should be able to `merge` with `how='outer'` and `indicator=True`, then count the observations where `['_merge'] != 'both'`

Comment: You can use len(df) to know how many entries are in each data frame and then compare. With an example of the 3 data frames it would be easier to visualize the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide your code and dataframes, it is not clear what is the output of your three dataframes join. also you should consider the pandas default [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join) is left join so rearranging dataframes could change results.

However, It doesn't change the solution. I assume you have a dataframe named df( which you said you made it by join) and you are looking for all missing indices in df which exists on those three dataframes.

first step is joining all dataframes with `how = 'outer'` parameter. the output should have all the indices for all dataframes`([df1,df2,df3])`. The second step is as easy as getting difference on indices for full_df and df.

Here is the code

```
   full_df = pd.join([df1,df2,df3], how = 'outer') 
   missing_indices = full_df.index.difference(df.index)
   print(missing_indices)
```